# When did this shipment of Babylonian painted tiles for the Louvre sink?

Tags: art, ancient-babylon

In her 1887 textbook "[History of Art for Beginners and Students](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/24726/24726-h/24726-h.htm)" Clara Erskine Clement wrote:

> A whole cargo of fragments of Babylonish tile-paintings was once
> collected for the gallery of the Louvre at Paris, and, when on board a
> ship and ready to be sent away, by some accident the whole was sunk.
>
> From the descriptions of them which were written, we find that there
> were portions of pictures of human faces and other parts of the body,
> of animals, mountains, and forests, of water, walls, and trees.

Does anyone know anything of this accident?

Comment: Is this the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dur-Sharrukin#The_Qurnah_Disaster  of 1855, as  described in https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/the-qurnah-disaster/ ?

Comment: @kimchilover thanks! I think it is

Comment: See also https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/orient1960/8/0/8_0_1/_pdf/-char/en

Comment: @kimchilover - It might be worth putting that material and a little something about it into an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems likely to me that Clement was referring to the "Qurnah Disaster", named after [Al Qurnah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qurnah) in Iraq, about 75 km north of Basra:

> In 1855, Al Qurnah was the site where local tribes attacked and sank a convoy of a ship and rafts carrying 240 cases of antiquities discovered by Victor Place's mission to Khorsabad, Rawlinson's to Kuyunjik and Fresnel's to Babylon. The loss of priceless antiquities was a notable disaster for those researching the antiquities of the region. Subsequent efforts to recover antiquities lost in the Qurnah Disaster, including a Japanese expedition in 1971-2, were largely unsuccessful.

The loss amounted to  decades' worth of collections by several different archaeological expeditions.

A more detailed account is [here](https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/the-qurnah-disaster/); the [report](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/orient1960/8/0/8_0_1/_pdf) of the Japanese recovery effort is also interesting.

I don't know how widely known this story was a few decades later, when Clement wrote her book. I don't believe it was widely published until the 20th century.

Comment: It is quite noteworthy that the shipment _'disappeared'_ — in a river (big, but not that deep and the spot quite localised?) — and that the most satisfactory result of eg the Japanese effort was that all members of the team 'returned home safely'? IMO: it is not at all clear that the ship/shipment actually sank at all, but may have been raided or whatever. An amount of stuff lost "to open up 4 international museums" seems rather big to vanish just like told (perhaps include the circumstances of reporting this 'loss'?)